# Optionally serialize a property based on its runtime value

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Fundamentally, I want to include or omit a property from the generated Json based on its value at the time of serialization.

More-specifically, I have a type that knows if a value has been assigned to it and I only want to serialize properties of that type if there *has* been something assigned to it (so I need to inspect the value at runtime).  I'm trying to make it easy for my API to detect the difference between "has the default value" and "wasn't specified at all".

A custom JsonConverter does not seem sufficient; I tried it and I believe the property name is already serialized before the converter is called.  In my case I want to omit even the property name.

I've looked at extending DefaultContractResolver but CreateProperty and CreateProperties (which return JsonProperty serialization metadata) take only the Type being serialized, so I can't inspect the instance itself.  In general, I don't see anything on the DefaultContractResolver allowing me to control *if* an instance is serialized; maybe I missed it.

I also thought maybe I needed to create a ContractResolver that returned a custom JsonObjectContract for my type.  But, again, I don't see anything on JsonObjectContract that makes decisions based on an instance.

Is there a good way to accomplish my goal?  Am I just missing something simple?  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.  Since Json.NET is so extensible, I thought this wouldn't be too hard.  But I'm starting to think I'm way off in the weeds here. :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make sure the data you're feeding is in the proper format for serialization? Specifically use an anonmyous type or projection in a  LINQ query to get the data just the way you want it.

Comment: @RickStrahl - I happen to work with Amber. The reason this won't work is that the fields to include or exclude are dynamic, and part of the protocol we're using. Put another way, a field that is not included in the serialization means something different than the field appearing with some value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, after digging around in Json.NET source for a while, I finally got this working and it will even honor the ShouldSerialize* and *Specified members that Json.NET supports.  Be warned: this is definitely going off into the weeds.

So I realized that the JsonProperty class returned by DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperty has ShouldSerialize and Converter properties, which allow me to specify *if* the property instance should actually be serialized and, if so, *how* to do it.

Deserialization requires something a little different, though.  DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract will, by default for a custom type, return a JsonObjectContract with a null Converter property.  In order to deserialize my type properly, I needed to set the Converter property when the contract is for my type.

Here's the code (with error handling / etc removed to keep things as small as possible).

First, the type that needs special handling:

```
public struct Optional<T>
{
    public readonly bool ValueProvided;
    public readonly T Value;

    private Optional( T value )
    {
        this.ValueProvided = true;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Optional<T>( T value )
    {
        return new Optional<T>( value );
    }
}
```

And there's the converter that will serialize it properly *after we know it should be serialized*:

```
public class OptionalJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public static OptionalJsonConverter<T> Instance = new OptionalJsonConverter<T>();

    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        var optional = (Optional<T>)value; // Cast so we can access the Optional<T> members
        serializer.Serialize( writer, optional.Value );
    }

    public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        var valueType = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
        var innerValue = (T)serializer.Deserialize( reader, valueType );
        return (Optional<T>)innerValue; // Explicitly invoke the conversion from T to Optional<T>
    }

    public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
        return objectType == typeof( Optional<T> );
    }
}
```

Finally, and most-verbosely, here's the ContractResolver that inserts the hooks:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // For deserialization. Detect when the type is being deserialized and set the converter for it.
    public override JsonContract ResolveContract( Type type )
    {
        var contract = base.ResolveContract( type );
        if( contract.Converter == null && type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( Optional<> ) )
        {
            // This may look fancy but it's just calling GetOptionalJsonConverter<T> with the correct T
            var optionalValueType = type.GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
            var genericMethod = this.GetAndMakeGenericMethod( "GetOptionalJsonConverter", optionalValueType );
            var converter = (JsonConverter)genericMethod.Invoke( null, null );
            // Set the converter for the type
            contract.Converter = converter;
        }
        return contract;
    }

    public static OptionalJsonConverter<T> GetOptionalJsonConverter<T>()
    {
        return OptionalJsonConverter<T>.Instance;
    }

    // For serialization. Detect when we're creating a JsonProperty for an Optional<T> member and modify it accordingly.
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty( MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization )
    {
        var jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty( member, memberSerialization );
        var type = jsonProperty.PropertyType;
        if( type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( Optional<> ) )
        {
            // This may look fancy but it's just calling SetJsonPropertyValuesForOptionalMember<T> with the correct T
            var optionalValueType = type.GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
            var genericMethod = this.GetAndMakeGenericMethod( "SetJsonPropertyValuesForOptionalMember", optionalValueType );
            genericMethod.Invoke( null, new object[]{ member.Name, jsonProperty } );
        }
        return jsonProperty;
    }

    public static void SetJsonPropertyValuesForOptionalMember<T>( string memberName, JsonProperty jsonProperty )
    {
        if( jsonProperty.ShouldSerialize == null ) // Honor ShouldSerialize*
        {
            jsonProperty.ShouldSerialize =
                ( declaringObject ) =>
                {
                    if( jsonProperty.GetIsSpecified != null && jsonProperty.GetIsSpecified( declaringObject ) ) // Honor *Specified
                    {
                        return true;
                    }                    
                    object optionalValue;
                    if( !TryGetPropertyValue( declaringObject, memberName, out optionalValue ) &&
                        !TryGetFieldValue( declaringObject, memberName, out optionalValue ) )
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException( "Better error message here" );
                    }
                    return ( (Optional<T>)optionalValue ).ValueProvided;
                };
        }
        if( jsonProperty.Converter == null )
        {
            jsonProperty.Converter = CustomContractResolver.GetOptionalJsonConverter<T>();
        }
    }

    // Utility methods used in this class
    private MethodInfo GetAndMakeGenericMethod( string methodName, params Type[] typeArguments )
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod( methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );
        return method.MakeGenericMethod( typeArguments );
    }

    private static bool TryGetPropertyValue( object declaringObject, string propertyName, out object value )
    {
        var propertyInfo = declaringObject.GetType().GetProperty( propertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
        if( propertyInfo == null )
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
        value = propertyInfo.GetValue( declaringObject, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null );
        return true;
    }

    private static bool TryGetFieldValue( object declaringObject, string fieldName, out object value )
    {
        var fieldInfo = declaringObject.GetType().GetField( fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
        if( fieldInfo == null )
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
        value = fieldInfo.GetValue( declaringObject );
        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps somebody else. Feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear or if it looks like I missed something.

Comment: I've just posted a feature request here https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1488

Answer (score 4):

Because you are asking to do it based on the value of a property what you can do is put the data into a dictionary. You can exclude adding the value to the dictionary. Below is a simple example of how to get the data out of an object.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void ConvertTest()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var @class = new Class1 { Name = "Joe" };

        var propertyInfos = typeof (Class1).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            dictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(@class, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null));
        }

        var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
        var o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@class);

        Console.WriteLine(serializeObject);
        Console.WriteLine(o);

        var class1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(serializeObject);
        Console.WriteLine(class1.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact your code looks like a unit test without being one almost made me miss the excellent point you're making. I don't know if it would solve OP question, but my initial tests seems to show that it solved my issue that was close to OP's.