# Json Ignore when writing default in certain Type C#

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

Is it possible on `System.Text.Json` to conditionally ignore when default if it is a certain type?

Because I have this type

```cs
public struct Optional<T>
{
    public bool HasValue { get; init; } 
    public T Value { get; init; } 

    public Optional(T value) =>
        (HasValue, Value)  = (true, value);
}
```

I can ignore it when default globally with `JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition` but this also means if I have a `bool` with false value or `int` with 0 value it will be ignored, and I only want to ignore when default if the type is specifically `Optional<T>`

Any suggestions?

Also, I don't want to use `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]`, I know I can do that but I want to make it globally with that certain type

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it in .NET 5 other than a global converter factory for the type(s) containing `Optional<T>` properties such as the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431434/3744182) to [Custom JSON serializer for optional property with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63418549/3744182).

Comment: In .NET 6 Microsoft is apparently exposing their metadata to application developers via [`JsonTypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinfo?view=net-6.0).  This looks to correspond to Json.NET's `JsonContract` type so programmatically adding `JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition` to all `Optional<T>` properties in runtime might become much easier in .NET 6.

Comment: I think it should work, I will try and hope it works, thank you very much for the help. 

Comment: How about the JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull