# How to use System.Text.Json to deserialize fields that have implicit conversion (implicit operator)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, implicit-conversion, system.text.json

I have an `Optional` struct that defines an implicit conversion from the original type:

```
public readonly struct Optional<T>
{
    // Some code removed to make the example simpler: original code: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Optional.cs
    public static implicit operator Optional<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Optional<T>(value);
    }
}
```

This means that e.g. this will work:

```
Optional<long> field = 5;
```

Now I want to deserialize json to a class that contains this struct:

```
public class Foo
{
   Optional<long> Bar {get; set;}
}
------
{
   "Bar": 5
}
```

Right now deserializing this json causes this exception:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException The JSON value could not be converted
> to Optional`1[System.Int64].

Is there a way to make this work?

P.S. This actually works out of the box in Newtonsoft.Json:

```
var a = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>("{\"Bar\":45}"); // This fails
var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{\"Bar\":45}"); // This works
```

Comment: I get a compilation error for your "struct" code: 'Program.Optional<T>' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: I just made it "simpler" to avoid too many lines, I'll add a reference to a full class

Comment: There's no support for that built in to System.Text.Json AFAIK.  You'll need to use the [`JsonConverter` factory pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#sample-factory-pattern-converter) as shown in [Custom JSON serializer for optional property with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63418549/3744182).  (The question has the required factory for `Optional<T>`.)  In fact, does that question answer yours?

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I have actually found that I already use JsonConverter to serialize Optional probably from that answer :) Adding the same `JsonConverter` to the settings for deserialization just made it work!