# How to use [JsonIgnore] when serializing a collection of derived types

Tags: c#, system.text.json

Environment: .NET 6 WebAPI app

I have two classes, base an derived, that both can be used to serialize the output of a certain method as JSON and send it to client. They look like this:

```
public class Base
{
  public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
  public string? Prop2 { get; set; }
  public long? Prop3 { get; set; }
  ...
}

public class Derived: Base 
{
  [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
  public new int? Prop1 { get; set; }
  [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
  public new string? Prop2 { get; set; }
  [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
  public new long? Prop3 { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

and a generic model class that has a collection of Base objects:

```
public class Model
{
  public List<Base>? Properties { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

I would like to always serialize the keys of `Base` objects inside the `Properties` collection, but skip the keys where the values are `null` if I'm serializing a collection of `Derived` objects. Sample code of what I want to achieve:

```
  var baseModel = new Model{ Properties = new List<Base>{ new Base { Prop1 = 1 } } };
  var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(baseModel);
  // This returns '{ "properties": { "Prop1": 1, "Prop2": null, "Prop3": null }}'

  var derivedModel = new Model { Properties = new List<Derived>{ new Derived { Prop1 = 1 }}};
  // This doesn't compile because of type mismatch
  
  var derivedModel2 = new Model { Properties = new List<Base>{ (Base)new Derived { Prop1 = 1 }}}; 
  // This works, but also returns '{ "properties": { "Prop1": 1, "Prop2": null, "Prop3": null }}'
  // I need to get '{ "properties": { "Prop1": 1 } }' here
```

Any advice on where to look?

UPD: I've considered a generic class use, but my model is currently used in the following manner (simplified):

```
public class BusinessLogic: IBusinessLogic
{
  ... // Constructor with DI etc.
  public async Task<Model> GetStuff(...)
  {
    ...
    var model = GetModelInternal(...);
    ...
    return model;
  }
}

public interface IBusinessLogic
{
  ...
  public Task<Model> GetStuff(...);
  ...
} 

public class MyController: ApiController
{
  protected readonly IBusinessLogic _bl;
  public MyController(..., IBusinessLogic bl)
  {
    _bl = bl;
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetStuff(bool baseOrDerived, ...)
  {
    var model = await _bl.GetModel(baseOrDerived, ...);
    return Json(model);
  }
}
```

The type of the return objects (Base or Derived) needs to depend upon the input parameter `baseOrDerived` that I get from the API client. This means that in order to use a generic I would need to pass the type parameter all the way through the controller. Moreover, I will have to introduce the same parameter to the `IBusinessLogic/BusinessLogic` pair and instead of simply getting `IBusinessLogic` instance from the DI, I would have to get a `ServiceProvider` instance there, create a scope inside the action and construct templated instance of `IBusinessLogic` dynamically. Given that this is NOT the only class I want this behavior from, this seems a real overkill to me.

Comment: I guess my road goes in the direction of a custom `ContractResolver` for this.

Comment: Do you only need to serialize, or also deserialize?

Comment: @dbc Only serialize. I'm using a distinctively different model with its own class for creating new objects of this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When serializing a polymorphic type hierarchy, System.Text.Json derives a contract for each object to be serialized from how the object is **declared** rather than its actual, concrete type.  Thus if I create an instance of `Derived` and serialize it as both `Derived` and `Base` and, I get different results: `{}` for `Derived` but  `{"Prop1":null,"Prop2":null,"Prop3":null}` for `Base`:

```
var model = new Derived ();

Console.WriteLine("JSON when serialized as {0}", nameof(Derived));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<Derived>(model));  // Outputs {}

Console.WriteLine("JSON when serialized as {0}", nameof(Base));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<Base>(model));     // Outputs {"Prop1":null,"Prop2":null,"Prop3":null}
```

Note, however, that there is one important exception: if the value to be serialized is declared as **`object`**, it will be serialized as its actual, concrete type:

```
Console.WriteLine("JSON when serialized as {0}", nameof(System.Object));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(model));     // Outputs {}
```

For details, see [Serialize properties of derived classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-6-0#serialize-properties-of-derived-classes).

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6EoQAL).

Thus, **assuming you only need to serialize**, you may modify your `Model` by adding a surrogate `IEnumerable<object>` property for `Properties` as follows:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Base>? Properties { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName(nameof(Properties))] // Surrogate property for Properties with items declared as object
    public IEnumerable<object>? SerializedProperties => Properties?.AsEnumerable();
}
```

And the contents of `Properties` will be serialized as `Base` or `Derived` depending upon their actual, concrete type.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cBgBK4).

Incidentally, your definition of `Derived` seems a little awkward because you are simply **masking** the properties of the base class.  You might consider making them virtual, and overriding them instead:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual int? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string? Prop2 { get; set; }
    public virtual long? Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived: Base 
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public override int? Prop1 { get => base.Prop1; set => base.Prop1 = value; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public override string? Prop2 { get => base.Prop2; set => base.Prop2 = value; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public override long? Prop3 { get => base.Prop3; set => base.Prop3 = value; }
}
```

You will get the same serialization results without the duplication of properties.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5kbZr3).

Incidentally, **in .NET 7** you will will not need to use a surrogate `object` property, you will be able to indicate that objects of type `Derived` should be serialized a such even when declared as `Base` by adding [`[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived))]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonderivedtypeattribute?view=net-7.0) to `Base`:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Derived))]
public class Base
{
    // Remainder unchanged
```

.NET 7 will also support [Conditional serialization via contract customization](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#example-conditional-serialization) which might allow you to achieve your required serialization results without needing a type hierarchy at all.

**As an alternative**, if you have nullable properties that you sometimes want to serialize, and sometimes don't, you might want to consider using the `Optional<T>` pattern as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63418549/3744182) by [Maxime Rossini](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63418549/3744182).  That question defines `Optional<T>` as follows:

> ```
> //  Converter from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418549/custom-json-serializer-for-optional-property-with-system-text-json/
> //  With the fix for OptionalConverterInner<T>.Write() taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431434/3744182
> [JsonConverter(typeof(OptionalConverter))]
> public readonly struct Optional<T>
> {
>     public Optional(T value)
>     {
>         this.HasValue = true;
>         this.Value = value;
>     }
>
>     public bool HasValue { get; }
>     public T Value { get; }
>     public static implicit operator Optional<T>(T value) => new Optional<T>(value);
>     public override string ToString() => this.HasValue ? (this.Value?.ToString() ?? "null") : "unspecified";
> }
> ```

If you redefine your `Base` as follows:

```
public class Base
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public Optional<int?> Prop1 { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public Optional<string?> Prop2 { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public Optional<long?> Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can completely eliminate the need for `Derived`.  With this model, `Prop1`, `Prop2` and `Prop3` will only be serialized when set **explicitly**, so you will be able to do something like:

```
// Explicitly set null properties if baseOrDerived is false
var item = baseOrDerived ? new Base { Prop2 = "hello" } : new Base { Prop1 = null, Prop2 = "hello", Prop3 = null };
```

And the result will be `{"Prop2":"hello"}` or `{"Prop1":null,"Prop2":"hello","Prop3":null}` depending upon whether `baseOrDerived` is true.

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r37F1g).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! The `IEnumerable<object>` solution might not work out-of-the-box since I also use the automatically generated Swagger documentation and this would screw it up. However, the new features coming in .NET 7 look really promising and just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make `Model` generic, like this:

```
public class Model<T> where T : Base
{
  public List<T>? Properties { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Now you should be able to do:

```
var derivedModel = new Model<Derived> { Properties = new List<Derived>{ new Derived { Prop1 = 1 }}};
```

Comment: I don't think I can specify a generic type as a return type of a certain method without specifying also generic's type parameter, right? Or without making the class that contains this method generic as well. I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `System.Text.Json`, have you tried configuring the serializer options to skip serializing null properties ? These options are available for other json serialization libraries (like Newtonsoft)

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
};
```

In case you want some property serialized anyway, just populate it with a reazonable default value.

For `[JsonIgnore]` alternative, have a look at [polymorphic serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

Comment: I have considered this as well, but the problem here is that my `Model` class contains several dozen properties, including different collections and more complex objects, and I want to apply different JsonIgnore conditions to different properties, also dynamically depending on the user's input.

Comment: Considering the attributes are difficult to apply dynamically based on user input, I think by making the fields in cause nullable and controlling their serialization by providing a default value or not, it's much more manageable and maintainable.

Comment: The fields _are_ actually nullable - my problem is that I have to keep them at null and sometimes show the keys with null value, sometimes not. If something is a list, it's quite difficult to provide a reasonable default that would mean "hide this" in a general case.

Comment: updated the response with a hint on polymorphic serialization. It could compose well with JsonIgnore attribute...

Comment: Thanks for the link on polymorphic serialization - I've just found it independently as well. It won't solve all the issues for me, but could be a good start - so, upvoted your answer.